# Finding entry with the latest date from a PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

The following PostgreSQL SELECT query always returns a result, because the `performance.query_plan` table has several entries with different `TIMESTAMP` values:

```
SELECT * FROM
  performance.query q,
  performance.query_plan AS qp
WHERE
  q.idx = qp.queryidx
  AND q.newplanneeded > qp.ts
LIMIT 1;
```

Out of these several entries in the `performance.query_plan` table I am only interested in the one with the LATEST timestamp value (stored in the `q.newplanneeded` column). How can I express that `qp.ts` in the WHERE condition should be equal to the MOST NEWLY ADDED row of the `performance.query_plan` table?

Comment: Are you looking for the latest plan of a single query or for all queries with an expired plan?

Comment: last plan of the single query

Comment: which query? that with a newest "newplanneeded", that with the most time difference, that with least (or greatest) expired plan ts? If you have two expired queries, how would you choose which one to return?

Comment: I have only one row 'q.newplanneeded' and several row qp.ts. Some row of qp.ts is older than the single q.newplanneeded and some are younger. Out of those several qp.ts I want to compare only the latest against the single q.newplanneeded, and if it  (the ts) older, the query should give me no result

Comment: do you need a record returned if the query does not have any plans at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  (q).*, (qp).*
FROM    (
        SELECT  q,
                (
                SELECT  qp
                FROM    query_plan qp
                WHERE   qp.queryidx = q.idx
                ORDER BY
                        ts DESC
                LIMIT   1
                ) qp
        FROM    query q
        ) qv
WHERE   (q).newplanneeded > (qp).ts
ORDER BY
        (q).idx
LIMIT   1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an `order by` on your query:

```
select * from
  performance.query q,
  performance.query_plan qp
WHERE
  q.idx = qp.queryidx
  AND q.newplanneeded < qp.ts
order by ts desc
limit 1;
```

I just flipped the direction of the comparison.

If all are `ts` and older than q.newplanneeded, then the query returns nothing.

If some are older and some are newer, then the newest value is returned.

Comment: that  won`t work, because it gives back an earlier entry. what I want is that if the LATEST entry is older than q.newplanneeded than it should not give back anything;

Comment: @pr123 . . . If the latest entry (by `ts`) is older than `q.newplanneeded`, then the query should return no rows.  The result set is empty because of the condition in the `where` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the query will return a record if there are both earlier and later plans for a record in `q`.

Comment: @Quassnoi . . . I am clearly missing something.  If there is both an earlier and later plan, then the latest entry is *not* older than `q.newplanneeded`.  It should be newer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes and that's why you should not return that entry

Comment: @GordonLinoff: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/85c06/2. A query on that dataset should return nothing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: again, this query will return a row: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/85c06/6. OP wants to return queries with `newplanneeded` later than the last existing plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct on (q.idx) *
from
  performance.query q,
  performance.query_plan qp
WHERE
  q.idx = qp.queryidx
order by q.idx, qp.ts desc
```